# iMacros Error code -921 Element was not found

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, runtime-error, imacros, error-code

I have iMacros for Firefox and keep running into this error code that prevents the Macro from completing. Furthermore, putting SET !ERRORIGNORE YES in does not seem to fix anything. The Macro simply runs, but does not visibly complete the last two steps.

Here's the Macro file:

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.mtv.com/content/movies/movie_brawl/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.mtv.com/content/movies/movie_brawl/buttons/vote.png
FRAME NAME="fancybox-frame1390149984424"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:mb2014_godzilla_vamp-form ATTR=ID:mb2014_godzilla_vamp-field-godzilla_vamp-godzilla
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:mb2014_godzilla_vamp-form ATTR=ID:mb2014_godzilla_vamp-submit
```

The error message:

```
RuntimeError: element IMG specified by SRC:http://www.mtv.com/content/movies/movie_brawl/buttons/vote.png was not found, line: 4 (Error code: -921)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the macro extension. Apparently it doesn't support the `data-srcover` attribute on `img` tag, which dynamically change the `src`. What end up recorded in the macro is the generated DOM with the full src, something that is not there when running the macro later.

You may want to edit the macro with this instead:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=DATA-SRCOVER:buttons/vote.png
```